# Merging maps in Go

Tags: go

What's the best way to merge key-value pairs from one map into another in Go? I'm using a simple loop, but I was wondering if there's something like PHP's `array_merge` that could be used.

```
bigmap := map[string]string{"a":"a", "b":"b", "c":"c"}
smallmap := map[string]string{"d":"d"}

for k, v := range smallmap {
    bigmap[k] = v
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't.

This wouldn't be so useful as the clear code you wrote is short enough and has the advantage of not hiding the implementation.

You can do your own function if you need it :

```
func addmap(a map[string]string, b map[string]string) {
    for k,v := range b {
        a[k] = v
    }
}

addmap(bigmap, smallmap)
```

But as Go has no generics, you would have to make a different function for each concrete map type you want to use.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me what is up with Go? It has none of the modern languages functionalities. Ternary operators: NOPE. Basic datastructure operations: NOPE. String manipulation utilities: NOPE... So much boilerplate code everywhere...

Comment: @AFP_555 Sure. There's a small bunch of purists trying to argue that their "style" is good programming, and calling it idiomatic go. Even if it gets in the way of the developer who just wants to get things done.

Comment: `func addmap(a map[string]interface{}, b map[string]interface{})` should even be better: https://play.golang.org/p/BE2mO0H51q6

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no built-in nor library function for that. And I think your code is as good as it can get.